# Are tokenized PostScript/GhostScript answers acceptable?

Tags: discussion, rules, answers

See [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26916/10619)).

I'm not sure how to deal with this answer. That's the shorter code at this time, so it may be the winner.

On one hand, the tokenized version is sort of compressed code, but it seems to be totally unreadable by an human. So I'm not sure if counting the characters of the tokenized version is fair. On the other hand, it's a feature from the language so it doesn't break any rule.

What do you think? Are there other languages which can be *compressed* on similar ways?

I haven't seen this discussion on meta yet so I'm posting it, it may be useful if somebody asks the same thing.

Comment: I started [a similar discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15392288#15392288) a few days ago, which you might want to read. I was mostly worried that if we allow this, by extension, compiled or zipped code sizes might be valid, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Despite being a moderator, I'm not speaking for the whole site in this instance. I am just speaking as a user.*

I consider that valid. It's not required for the code to be human-readable. We allow submissions in GolfScript or object code, after all.

Comment: Even if I don't know the GolfScript syntax, I can read it when code is posted in a answer. With tokenized PostScript/GhostScript, it can't be displayed as plain text, it's necessary to use `hexdump`.

Comment: @n.1, I've posted quite a few GolfScript answers which had to be encoded by hexdump because they use non-printing characters in strings.

Comment: @PeterTaylor should we require answers to use printable characters only?

Comment: @JanDvorak, I don't think so. If the standard interpreter treats `?` as `\u0004` then a golfer would be crazy not to exploit that. Similarly where the standard interpreter provides aliases for keywords, so Chris' analogy is a good one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments, I followed your advice and accepted the answer.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I tried requiring that in [this challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4356/say-hello-to-the-world-in-ascii-art). It seemed to work OK, although I'm not sure it really can be said to have improved readability.

Answer (score 2):

Since Postscript's binary tokens are in 1-to-1 correspondence with the regular ascii words, it's only polite to provide a full ascii version as well.

But if the binary version is correctly executed by the interpreter, that would appear to be the definition of *valid* (unless, of course, ascii-only were an explicit requirement of the challenge).

I hasten (after actually looking at the linked question) to add that even the authors of these binary postscript programs are reluctant to take the idea *too far*, because it gets sooooo weird so fast.